# Why is my Infix to postfix program giving the wrong output (C, Stacks)

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, stack

**Introduction:**
I am coding an infix to postfix program in the C programming language using static char stack (using struct and char array).

**My Methadology:** I usually start out with working code and make is cleaner and smaller later on (when I know the algorithm works).

**Done:** I have only finished my basic rough code of the program and it's giving me the wrong output so I went over it a few times myself and showed it to my friend, who also couldn't quite figure it out.

**Ask:** It would really help me out and possibly make me a better programmer if someone could please give this a look and tell me why I am getting the wrong output and if possible, point me in the right direction.

**Insight:** The problem I am getting is that instead of adding a +, -, * or / after the alphanumeric part (like so A+B would be AB+), it gives random characters in their place (like so AB| or AB├ etc). These characters change on every execution of the program. I believe they are garbage values but am not sure how they are being used.

[image]

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 20

struct stackObj{

    char stack[MAX];
    int topOfStack;

};

void stackPush(struct stackObj *s, char value);
char stackPop(struct stackObj *s);
void stackPeekPrint(struct stackObj *s);
char stackPeek(struct stackObj *s);
int stackIsEmpty(struct stackObj *s);
int stackIsFull(struct stackObj *s);

int comparePrecedence(struct stackObj *s, char value);


int main(){

    struct stackObj s;
    s.topOfStack=0;

    char result[MAX];
    int resultFlag=0;

    char exp[MAX];
    gets(exp);

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Expression:\t");
    printf(exp);
    printf("\n\n");


    char _new='.';
    char _old='.';
    int i=0;
    while (exp[i]!= '\0'){

        _new = exp[i];
        i++;

        if (_new=='+' || _new=='-' || _new=='*' || _new=='/'){

            if (comparePrecedence(&s,_new)==1){
                stackPush(&s,_new);

            } else if (comparePrecedence(&s,_new)==0){
                _old = stackPop(&s);
                result[resultFlag]=_old;
                resultFlag++;
                stackPush(&s,_new);
            }

        } else  if (_new=='('){
            stackPush(&s,_new);
        }

        else  if (_new==')'){
            _old = stackPop(&s);
            while (_old != '('){
                result[resultFlag]=_old;
                resultFlag++;
                _old = stackPop(&s);
            }
            stackPop(&s);

        } else if (isalnum(_new) ) {
            result[resultFlag]=_new;
            resultFlag++;
        }
    }

    while (s.topOfStack > 0) {
        _old = stackPop(&s);
        result[resultFlag]=_old;
        resultFlag++;

    }

    printf("\n\n\n");
    printf(result);
    printf("\n\n\n");


    return 0;
}

//----------------- Precedence Comparison CODE -----------------------------

int comparePrecedence(struct stackObj *s, char value){

    //START - Variable Declarations and Definitions
    int stackPrecedence = 0;
    int operatorPrecedence = 0;

    char stackChar = stackPeek(s);
    char operChar = value;
    //END - Variable Declarations and Definitions


    //START - Setting Precedences
    if (stackChar== '+'){ stackPrecedence=1; }
    else if (stackChar== '-'){ stackPrecedence=1; }
    else if (stackChar== '*'){ stackPrecedence=2; }
    else if (stackChar== '/'){ stackPrecedence=2; }

    if (operChar== '+'){ operatorPrecedence=1; }
    else if (operChar== '-'){ operatorPrecedence=1; }
    else if (operChar== '*'){ operatorPrecedence=2; }
    else if (operChar== '/'){ operatorPrecedence=2; }
    //END - Setting Precedences


    //START - Comparing Precedences
    if (operatorPrecedence > stackPrecedence) { return 1;
    } else { return 0; }

}


//----------------- STACK CODE ------------------------------------------

void stackPush(struct stackObj *s, char value){

    if ( (stackIsFull(s) != 1) && (s->topOfStack != MAX) ){

        s->stack[s->topOfStack] = value;
        s->topOfStack++;

    } else {
        printf("\nSorry, stack is full. No new data can be entered");
    }


}

char stackPop(struct stackObj *s){

    s->topOfStack = s->topOfStack-1;
    return s->stack[s->topOfStack-1];


}

void stackPeekPrint(struct stackObj *s){

    if (s->topOfStack != 0){
        printf("\nTOS:\t%c", s->stack[(s->topOfStack)-1]);
    } else {
        printf("\nSorry stack is empty");
    }

}

char stackPeek(struct stackObj *s){

    if (s->topOfStack != 0){
        return (s->stack[(s->topOfStack)-1]);
    } else {
        return '`';
    }

}

int stackIsEmpty(struct stackObj *s){

    if (s->topOfStack==0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}

int stackIsFull(struct stackObj *s){

    if (s->topOfStack==MAX) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: let me guess: you're forgetting to nul-terminate your result string?

Comment: `topOfStack` is the index to push the next item - kind of misnamed. In `stackPop()`, you return the wrong item. You should `return s->stack[s->topOfStack];` - since in the line before, you decrement `topOfStack`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Even of I dont add a nul-terminate, woulndt by string be more like AB+randomChar rather than ABrandomChar?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp THANK YOU SO MUCH MAN... This really helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `stackPop()` Function you are doing

```
 s->topOfStack = s->topOfStack-1;
 return s->stack[s->topOfStack-1];
```

It should be

```
 s->topOfStack = s->topOfStack-1;
 return s->stack[s->topOfStack];
```

you are actually returning `s->stack[s->topOfStack-2]`.